# 2*2 matrix operation in java script enter. matrix from user into text box

Tags: javascript, html

//java script file , here i am using promt to enter input from user but what i want is user must enter input directly into the textbox1(matrix 1) ,textbox2(matrix2) ,result(textbox3)

```js
var a = [];//empty array
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  a.push(Number(prompt("Enter 1 matrix of element " + (i + 1))));

}
document.getElementById("txt1").value = a;

var b = [];
var j;
for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
  b.push(Number(prompt("Enter 2 matrix of element " + (j + 1))));
}

document.getElementById("txt2").value = b;

var c1 = (a[0] * b[0]) + (a[1] * b[2]);
var c2 = (a[0] * b[1]) + (a[1] * b[3]);
var c3 = (a[2] * b[0]) + (a[3] * b[2]);
var c4 = (a[2] * b[1]) + (a[3] * b[3]);
var g = c1 + "  " + c2 + " " + c3 + " " + c4;

function validate() {
  document.getElementById('txtResult').value = g;
}
```

```html
//html

<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="JavaScript.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="f1">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    first matrix
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txt1" />
                </td>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        second matrix
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" id="txt2" />
                    </td>
                    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" id="b1" value="Result" onclick="validate()" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtResult" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**design page matrix 1 in textbox1 and matrix 2 in text box 2 after clicking button result must display in textbox 3**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can accept a comma separated input from the user in the `txt1` and `txt2` textbox then split those values using comma, which will return you the array of numbers which is what you are creating in prompt. So, finally rest of your code can be used to calculate the value for `txtResult` which you get on click of `Result` button.

The below code assumes that user input four numbers separated by comma. You can add further validations on it based on your requirement.

```js
function validate() {
    var a = document.getElementById("txt1").value.split(',');
    var b = document.getElementById("txt2").value.split(',');
    var c1 = (a[0] * b[0]) + (a[1] * b[2]);
    var c2 = (a[0] * b[1]) + (a[1] * b[3]);
    var c3 = (a[2] * b[0]) + (a[3] * b[2]);
    var c4 = (a[2] * b[1]) + (a[3] * b[3]);
    var  g = c1 + "  " + c2 + " " + c3 + " " + c4;
    document.getElementById('txtResult').value = g;
}
```

```html
 <form id="f1">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                first matrix
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txt1" />
            </td>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    second matrix
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txt2" />
                </td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="b1" value="Result" onclick="validate()" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="txtResult" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: @Nikhila please give accept tick(green tick) to his answer so that every one knows that this one is working